# How to deal with Haskell's reserved keywords in record fields?

Tags: haskell, aeson

JSON in response of [Github Gists Rest API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#list-a-users-gists) contains [Haskell's keyword](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#type) `type`. But `type` couldn't be used as a record field.

Thus it couldn't be used in implementation of [Aeson's Generic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:1) FromJSON/ToJSON instances.

```
import Data.Text (Text)

import GHC.Generics (Generic)

type URL = Text

data OwnerType = User deriving (Show)

data Owner = Owner {
      id :: Int,
      gravatar_id :: Text,
      login :: Text,
      avatar_url :: Text,
      events_url :: URL,
      followers_url :: URL,
      following_url :: URL,
      gists_url :: URL,
      html_url :: URL,
      organizations_url :: URL,
      received_events_url :: URL,
      repos_url :: URL,
      starred_url :: URL,
      subscriptions_url :: URL,
      url :: URL,
      -- type :: Text,
      site_admin :: Bool
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ToJSON Owner
instance FromJSON Owner
```

**Question**:
Is there a proper approach to deal with such kind of conflicts?

Comment: You can implement your own `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` and then thus perform the "*key translation*" so to speak.

Comment: I'll try this approach also. BTW thank you for your TemplateHaskell-answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can solve this by using `TemplateHaskell`. Instead of writing `ToJSON` and `FromJON`, we can use a specific mapping of the keys.

First of all, we have to construct a name for the field that is *not* type, for instance:

```
data Owner = Owner {
      id :: Int,
      gravatar_id :: Text,
      login :: Text,
      avatar_url :: Text,
      events_url :: URL,
      followers_url :: URL,
      following_url :: URL,
      gists_url :: URL,
      html_url :: URL,
      organizations_url :: URL,
      received_events_url :: URL,
      repos_url :: URL,
      starred_url :: URL,
      subscriptions_url :: URL,
      url :: URL,
      owner_type :: Text,
      site_admin :: Bool
  } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

Now we can use the [**`deriveJSON :: Options -> Name -> Q [Dec]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html#v:deriveJSON) function that will construct a `fromJSON` and `toJSON` instance.

The key here is the [**`Options`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html#t:Options) parameter: it contains a **`fieldLabelModifier :: String -> String`** field that can rewrite the names of the fields to the keys in JSON. We can thus here generate a function that will rewrite it.

So we first construct a function `ownerFieldRename :: String -> String`:

```
ownerFieldRename :: String -> String
ownerFieldRename "owner_type" = "type"
ownerFieldRename name = name
```

So this function acts as an identity function, except for `"owner_type"`, which is mapped on `"type"`.

So now we can call the `deriveJSON` function with custom options like:

```
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = ownerFieldRename} ''Owner)
```

Or in full:

**`RenameUtils.hs`**:

```
module RenameUtils where

ownerFieldRename :: String -> String
ownerFieldRename "owner_type" = "type"
ownerFieldRename name = name
```

**`MainFile.hs`**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Aeson.TH(deriveJSON, defaultOptions, Options(fieldLabelModifier))
import RenameUtils(ownerFieldRename)

import Data.Text (Text)

type URL = Text

data Owner = Owner {
      id :: Int,
      gravatar_id :: Text,
      login :: Text,
      avatar_url :: Text,
      events_url :: URL,
      followers_url :: URL,
      following_url :: URL,
      gists_url :: URL,
      html_url :: URL,
      organizations_url :: URL,
      received_events_url :: URL,
      repos_url :: URL,
      starred_url :: URL,
      subscriptions_url :: URL,
      url :: URL,
      owner_type :: Text,
      site_admin :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = ownerFieldRename} ''Owner)
```

Now we obtain a JSON object with `type` as key:

```
Prelude Main Data.Aeson> encode (Owner 1 "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" True)
"{\"id\":1,\"gravatar_id\":\"\",\"login\":\"\",\"avatar_url\":\"\",\"events_url\":\"\",\"followers_url\":\"\",\"following_url\":\"\",\"gists_url\":\"\",\"html_url\":\"\",\"organizations_url\":\"\",\"received_events_url\":\"\",\"repos_url\":\"\",\"starred_url\":\"\",\"subscriptions_url\":\"\",\"url\":\"\",\"type\":\"\",\"site_admin\":true}"
```

For a simple `fieldLabelModifier` function we do not need to write a specific function (that we have to define in a specific module), we can also use an *lambda expression* here:

**`MainFile.hs`**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Aeson.TH(deriveJSON, defaultOptions, Options(fieldLabelModifier))
import Data.Text (Text)

type URL = Text

data Owner = Owner {
      id :: Int,
      gravatar_id :: Text,
      login :: Text,
      avatar_url :: Text,
      events_url :: URL,
      followers_url :: URL,
      following_url :: URL,
      gists_url :: URL,
      html_url :: URL,
      organizations_url :: URL,
      received_events_url :: URL,
      repos_url :: URL,
      starred_url :: URL,
      subscriptions_url :: URL,
      url :: URL,
      owner_type :: Text,
      site_admin :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = \x -> if x == "owner_type" then "type" else x} ''Owner)
```

Comment: please add `import Data.Text (Text)

type URL = T` to complete `MainFile.hs`

Answer (score 2):

Willem's answer may be the more appropriate one, and may fit what you want better, but here's another way, allowing you to define your non-conflicting data without having to write the ToJSON and FromJSON instances for it, defining the types

```
data OwnerData = OwnerData {
    oid :: Int
    -- ... other data with non-conflicting names
  } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

and

```
data Owner = Owner {
  owner_data :: OwnerData,
  user_type :: Text
} deriving (Show)
```

We can now define the following instances:

```
-- nothing special for OwnerData: 
instance ToJSON OwnerData
instance FromJSON OwnerData

-- a little helper function to extract the hashmap(Object) from a value
toObject :: ToJSON a => a -> Object
toObject a = case toJSON a of
  Object o -> o
  _        -> error "toObject: value isn't an Object"

-- the instances for Owner
instance ToJSON Owner where
  toJSON (Owner {owner_data = ownerData, user_type = userType}) = 
    Object $ 
    toObject ownerData <> HML.fromList ["type" .= userType]

  toEncoding (Owner {owner_data = ownerData, user_type = userType}) = 
    pairs . foldMap (uncurry (.=)) . HML.toList $ 
    toObject ownerData <> HML.fromList ["type" .= userType]

instance FromJSON Owner where
  parseJSON = withObject "Owner" $ \v -> do
    ownerData <- parseJSON (Object v)
    userType <- v .: "type"
    return Owner { owner_data = ownerData, user_type = userType }
```

The imports and language pragmas I used:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as HML (fromList, toList)
```