# Haskell type record syntax

Tags: haskell, aeson

Need Aeson to encode API commands, but one of the keywords I need in the type's record syntax is `data` which is obviously not allowed. How can I still use it?

```
data MatrixTX = MatrixTX    { op   :: T.Text
                            , data  :: T.Text 
                            , kwl      :: T.Text -- keyword list
                            , kw       :: T.Text -- keyword
                            } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48474587/67579