# Escaping Haskell record's field

Tags: json, api, haskell

### Question

Is there a way to create a record with a field called "data"?

```hs
data MyRecord =
  MyRecord {
    otherField :: String,
    data       :: String  -- compilation error
  }
```

### Why do I need it?

I've been writing a wrapper around a JSON API using Aeson and the remote service decided to call one of the fields `data`.

```json
{
  pagination: {
    ..
  },
  data: [ 
    { .. },
    { .. },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with Haskell's reserved keywords in record fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474587/how-to-deal-with-haskells-reserved-keywords-in-record-fields)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can name the field something else than `data`, like:

```
data MyRecord =
  MyRecord {
    otherField :: String,
    recordData :: String
  }
```

And then derive a `ToJSON` with a key modifier:

```
labelMapping :: String -> String
labelMapping "recordData" = "data"
labelMapping x = x

instance ToJSON MyRecord where
    toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
            fieldLabelModifier = labelMapping
        }

instance FromJSON Coord where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions {
            fieldLabelModifier = labelMapping
        }
```

Comment: I guess that for `FromJSON` I need to provide an inverted mapping, right?

Comment: @AlojzyLeszcz: no, if I recall correctly you can use the same `Options` object. It will exhaustively enumerate over the fields.

Comment: aeson sort of pushes you into this solution, but I'm uneasy with it because it's extremely "stringly typed". If you change the name of your field and forget to change the label mapping, your `FromJSON` instance is broken. I would manually write the parser instead.